# MVC view is not loading in a bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a MVC3 application in which I am using bootstrap files.
I am trying to open an AddEmployee.cshtml view (which is currently opening normally) in a bootstrap modal to add a new employee record.

The problem I am facing is that when I am creating a simple blank modal, it opens correctly but when I am trying to to load my above mentioned razor view in a modal, that modal doesn't work.
I want the link (on the click of which modal should be opened) on every page that's why I have that in my _Layout.cshtml.

I am pasting the code below for reference.

1) _Layout.cshtml

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="sidebar">
        @Html.Partial("_sidebar") //This has the link
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

2) _sidebar.cshtml:-

```
<div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align: right;">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" href="../Home/AddEmployee" data-toggle="modal" id="btnCreate">
    <input type="image" src="../../Images/addnewfinal.png" alt="Add New Allocation" id="btnAddNewAllocation" /><span id="spanAddNewEmployee">Add New Employee</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

3) Controller action:-

```
public class HomeController : Controller
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult AddEmployee()
     {
       .....
       return View();
     }
 }
```

4) AddEmployee.cshtml (which I want display in modal):-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addNew" aria-labelledby="#myLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLabel">Add New Employee
        </h4>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployee", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "testForm" }))
    {
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListOfEmployees)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">
                Close
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

5) EditorFor template (Employee.cshtml):-

```
<div class="form-group" id="div1">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { @placeholder = "Id", @class = "form-control", id="userId", name = "userId", onblur="Showavailability()"})
    <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @placeholder = "Name", @class = "form-control", name = "userName" })
    <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</span>
</div>
```

When I click on the link in _sidebar.cshtml, control goes to the controller action and than to Employee.cshtml also but modal doesn't get created, what I am getting is the faded screen only.

Is their any Javascript also needs to be written for this?
Please help me in resolving this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to render your AddEmployee.cshtml  as a partial so that it will appear in your page. Second I don't believe you can have both `href="../Home/AddEmployee"` and  `data-toggle="modal"` at the same time....My guess is that you want to open up this modal to ask for confirmation and then create it. If so you will also have to set the modal target for the button(link) too.

Comment: Steve - I dont want to ask for confirmation, just want to open up the AddEmployee.cshtml in the modal and add the record.

Comment: @VickySinghTomar then you will have to use javascript to listen to the on click event of the button, and make an ajax call. Bootstrap doesn't support multiple data-toggle if I remember rite. Everything else is the same